# Maclaurin series for $\sqrt{\frac{1}{1 - (x + \frac{1}{2})^2}}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

So, the problem was to find Maclaurin series for $\arctan\sqrt{\frac{1-2x}{1+2x}}$ using series of its derivative. The most obvious way to do it is to take derivative of $\arctan$, then find Maclaurin series for it and integrate it. But I wanted to go another way, so I derived the following formula:  $\arctan\sqrt{\frac{1-2x}{1+2x}} = \arccos\left(\frac{1+2x}{2}\right)$...which turned out to be wrong (Thanks to Mycroft for noticing it). The right formula is:
$$\arctan\sqrt{\frac{1-2x}{1+2x}} = \arccos\sqrt{\frac{1+2x}{2}}$$. Its derivative is $$- \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{1+2x}{2}\right)}}\cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{2}}}$$ and to find MacLaurin series for this function is not so hard. The question remains the same: how to find MacLaurin series for the derivative of first formula with $\arccos$ which is $$-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3-4x-4x^2}}$$. I can find its representation only for $x = -\frac{1}{2}$ that I don't need.

Comment: MacLaurin series is by definition the series at $x = 0$. Why can't you do it? The derivative is well defined at zero.

Comment: I think that it needed to be something like $(1+x)^\alpha$, but I can't simplify the function in this way near $0$.

Comment: The formula you derived is obviously wrong. Just take $x = 0$ as a try.

Comment: Yes, it turned out to be wrong. Sorry for this, I will correct it right now!

Comment: Corrected. Hope that now there are no such terrible mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taylor series at $x = x_0$:

$$f(x) \approx f(x_0) + \sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} f^{(k)}(x = x_0) \frac{(x-x_0)^k}{k!}$$

MacLaurin series is a special case where $x_0 = 0$.

For what concerns your function, it's all about derivatives:

$$f(x) = \arctan\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{1-2x}{1+2x}}\right)$$

$$f'(x) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4 x^2}}$$

$$f''(x) = -\frac{4 x}{\left(1-4 x^2\right)^{3/2}}$$

$$f'''(x) = -\frac{48 x^2}{\left(1-4 x^2\right)^{5/2}}-\frac{4}{\left(1-4 x^2\right)^{3/2}}$$

And so on.

At $x = 0$ you can easily see that

$$f(0) = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$$

$$f'(0) = -1$$

$$f''(0) = 0$$

$$f'''(0) = -4$$

Go on with derivatives and you will get

$$f(x) \approx \frac{\pi }{4}-x-\frac{2 x^3}{3}-\frac{6 x^5}{5}-\frac{20 x^7}{7}-\frac{70 x^9}{9}-\frac{252 x^{11}}{11}+O\left(x^{12}\right)$$

**The other function**

Let's instead search for MacLaurin series of

$$g(x) = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{1 - (x + 1/2)^2}}$$

The same speech holds.

$$g'(x) = \left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(\frac{1}{\frac{3}{4}-x (x+1)}\right)^{3/2}$$

$$g''(x) = 16 \left(\frac{1}{3-4 x (x+1)}\right)^{5/2} (4 x (x+1)+3)$$

$$g'''(x) = -\frac{96 (2 x+1) \sqrt{\frac{1}{3-4 x (x+1)}} (4 x (x+1)+7)}{(4 x (x+1)-3)^3}$$

And so on, if you want to have fun.

Again

$$g(0) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$$

$$g'(0) = \frac{4}{3 \sqrt{3}}$$

$$g''(0) = \frac{16}{3 \sqrt{3}}$$

$$g'''(0) = \frac{224}{9 \sqrt{3}}$$

And so on.

MacLaurin Series for this function is

$$g(x) \approx \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{4 x}{3 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{8 x^2}{3 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{112 x^3}{27 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{608 x^4}{81 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{1088 x^5}{81 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{6016 x^6}{243 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{33536 x^7}{729 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{20992 x^8}{243 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{3214336 x^9}{19683 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{18335744 x^{10}}{59049 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{35024896 x^{11}}{59049 \sqrt{3}}+O\left(x^{12}\right)$$

Comment: Sorry, but the question was to find MacLaurin series for square root function near $0$. This way turned out to be easy, but what I need was to derive a MacLaurin series for the function that is in the title of the question. But anyway, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @IPPK Ok. I am going to add it at the end of my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is to make use of the fact that whatever way you get the series, it is the same.

$\begin{align*}
  \sqrt{\frac{1}{1 - (x + 1/2)^2}}
    &= (1 - (x + 1/2)^2)^{-1/2} \\
    &= \sum_{n \ge 0} (-1)^n \binom{-1/2}{n} (x + 1/2)^{2 n} \\
    &= \sum_{n \ge 0} (-1)^n \binom{-1/2}{n}
         \sum_k 2^{- (2 n - k)} \binom{2 n}{k} x^k \\
    &= \sum_{n \ge 0} \sum_k 2^{2 n}
         \binom{2 n}{n} \binom{2 n}{k}2^{- (2 n - k)} x^k \\
    &= \sum_k \left(
                2^{-k} \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{2 n}{n} \binom{2 n}{k} 
              \right) x^k
\end{align*}$

Will need some serious machinery to get a closed form for the coefficients, though. I'd take a peek at Petkovsek, Wilf, Zeilberger's [*A = B*](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html) (A. K. Peters, 1996), the underlying algorithms to get closed forms for many such sums (or proving they don't exist) are available in most computer algebra systems.

Answer (score 0):

Considering $$y=\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-2x}{1+2x}}\right)$$ you could compose the series. Start with
$$\tan^{-1}(t)=\frac{\pi }{4}+\frac{t-1}{2}-\frac{1}{4} (t-1)^2+\frac{1}{12} (t-1)^3-\frac{1}{40}
   (t-1)^5+\frac{1}{48} (t-1)^6+O\left((t-1)^7\right)$$ Now, long division
$$\frac{1-2x}{1+2x}=1-4 x+8 x^2-16 x^3+32 x^4-64 x^5+128 x^6+O\left(x^7\right)$$ Binomial theorem 
$$\sqrt{\frac{1-2x}{1+2x}}=1-2 x+2 x^2-4 x^3+6 x^4-12 x^5+20 x^6+O\left(x^7\right)$$ makes
$$t-1=-2 x+2 x^2-4 x^3+6 x^4-12 x^5+20 x^6+O\left(x^7\right)$$ Computing the powers of $(t-1)$ to $O\left(x^7\right)$ gives finally
$$y=\frac{\pi }{4}-x-\frac{2 x^3}{3}-\frac{6 x^5}{5}+O\left(x^7\right)$$ which is in fact
$$y=\frac \pi 4-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\binom{2 n}{n}}{2 n+1} x^{2 n+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

By the Faa di Bruno formula and some properties of the partial Bell polynomials, we have
\begin{align*}
\biggl(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3-4x-4x^2}\,}\biggr)^{(n)}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_k\frac1{(3-4x-4x^2)^{1/2+k}} B_{n,k}(-4-8x,-8,0,\dotsc,0)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_k\frac{(-1)^k 8^k}{(3-4x-4x^2)^{1/2+k}} B_{n,k}\biggl(x+\frac12,1,0,\dotsc,0\biggr)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_k\frac{(-1)^k 8^k}{(3-4x-4x^2)^{1/2+k}} \frac{(n-k)!}{2^{n-k}}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{n-k}\biggl(x+\frac12\biggr)^{2k-n}\\
&\to \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\frac{(2k-1)!!}{2^k}\frac{(-1)^k 8^k}{3^{1/2+k}} \frac{(n-k)!}{2^{n-k}}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{n-k}\frac1{2^{2k-n}}, \quad x\to0\\
&=\frac{n!}{\sqrt{3}\,}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(2k-1)!!}{k!} \biggl(\frac{2}{3}\biggr)^k \binom{k}{n-k}
\end{align*}
for $n\ge0$, where we used the formula
\begin{equation}\label{Bell-x-1-0-eq}\tag{BQ}
B_{n,k}(x,1,0,\dotsc,0)
=\frac{(n-k)!}{2^{n-k}}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{n-k}x^{2k-n}.
\end{equation}
Consequently, we obtain
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3-4x-4x^2}\,}
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}\,} \sum_{n=0}^\infty\Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(2k-1)!!}{k!} \biggl(\frac{2}{3}\biggr)^k \binom{k}{n-k}\Biggr]x^n, \quad |x|<\frac12.
\end{equation*}
The formula \eqref{Bell-x-1-0-eq} was first established in the paper [1] and then reviewed in the article [2] below.

References

1. F. Qi and B.-N. Guo, *Explicit formulas for special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind and for the Euler numbers and polynomials*, Mediterr. J. Math. **14** (2017), no. 3, Article 140, 14 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-017-0939-1.
2. F. Qi, D.-W. Niu, D. Lim, and Y.-H. Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, J. Math. Anal. Appl. **491** (2020), no. 2, Article 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\arctan\sqrt{\frac{1-2x}{1+2x}}\,\to\frac\pi4$ as $x\to0$ and
\begin{align*}
\biggl(\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x^2}\,}\biggr)^{(n)}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_k\frac1{(1-4x^2)^{1/2+k}} B_{n,k}(-8x,-8,0,\dotsc,0)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_k\frac{(-8)^k}{(1-4x^2)^{1/2+k}} B_{n,k}(x,1,0,\dotsc,0)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\frac{(2k-1)!!}{2^k}\frac{(-8)^k}{(1-4x^2)^{1/2+k}} \frac{(n-k)!}{2^{n-k}}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{n-k}x^{2k-n}\\
&=\frac{n!}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{(1-4x^2)^{1/2+k}} \frac{2^{3k}(2k-1)!!}{k!}\binom{k}{n-k}x^{2k-n}\\
&\to\begin{cases}
0, & n=2m+1\\
2^{2m}[(2m-1)!!]^2, & n=2m
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
as $x\to0$ for $m,n\ge0$, we acquire
\begin{equation*}
\arctan\sqrt{\frac{1-2x}{1+2x}}\,
=\arccos\sqrt{\frac{1+2x}{2}}\,
=\frac\pi4+\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(2m-1)!!}{(2m)!!}(2x)^{2m}, \quad |x|<\frac12.
\end{equation*}
Replacing $2x$ by $x$ gives
\begin{equation*}
\arctan\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\,
=\arccos\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{2}}\,
=\frac\pi4+\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(2m-1)!!}{(2m)!!}x^{2m}, \quad |x|<1.
\end{equation*}
The references for looking up concepts and notions used above are the same ones as at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4672287.